# What statistical test is needed for this experiment? Is it a simple t-test?

Tags: regression, anova, repeated-measures, inference, experiment-design

Suppose I have data which is something like the table below, where I measure how an individual does on a task under 4 conditions. So we observe A, B, C, D for a given individual. There are $N$ individuals. Let's call $Y_i$ the task performance of individual $i$ where $Y_i$ is continuous.

I am primarily interested in $D-B$ (see table below), which is the extent to which boosting self-competency can increase post-reflection performance on a task.

Is an estimate of this simply $\alpha = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} [Y_{i,R=1,T=1} - Y_{i,R=1,T=0}]}{N}$

And so we just do a t-test on $\alpha$?

Alternatively: Is there a way to get this model $\alpha$ as a term in a regression model with interactions?

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|                                      | REFLECTION ON SELF COMPETENCY CONDITION    |
|                                      +---------------------+----------------------+
|                                      | No Reflection (R=0) | Yes Reflection (R=1) |
+-----------------+--------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
| SELF-COMPETENCY | Before Boost (T=0) | A                   | B                    |
| BOOST CONDITION +--------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
|                 | After Boost (T=1)  | C                   | D                    |
+-----------------+--------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Hmm but wouldn't you have to account for the correlation within an individual's scores? I'm not sure a chi-squared test does that. That's why I thought of differencing initially. Also, I forgot to add, but my DV is continuous

Comment: It may help to reframe you intuition by considering that you have two factors: self-competency boost, with two levels; and reflection on self competency, with two levels. Then the comparison between B and D becomes a contrast in a two-way ANOVA design, unless I misunderstand the description of your experimental setup.